# Would spinning a magnet in a coil of copper wire induce a Electromotive Force?

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, home-experiment

I would like to do a lab for school which compares the Electromotive Force generated by spinning different types of magnets (paramagnetic, diamagnetic and ferromagnetic), within a copper wire. However, I'm not certain my design for the generator will work. Ultimately my question is, in a generator design such as the one below, will a magnet spinning with unmoving polarities generate flux?

[image: diagram of design]

Comment: just to clarify the arrows just represent the spinning of the magnet.

Comment: So the coil is stationary and the magnet is moving?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your diagram correctly, nor am I sure that I understand your question

> "will a magnet spinning with unmoving polarities generate flux?"

However, it *appears* that there is no relative motion between the magnet and the coil. If my guess at what you mean is correct, the answer is NO, there will not be an emf induced in the coil.

However, with a very slight modification, you *will* get an EMF. If the coil is connected to a circuit that is NOT spinning, although their is no EMF induced *in the coil*, there will be an EMF induced in the *circuit*, i.e. because the magnet is moving relative to the circuit.

See [Faraday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox) for more information.